# Inverted L navigation - still valid in a responsive world?

Tags: navigation

I'm curious to know what people think about Inverted-L style navigation structures. For example: http://www.friendsreunited.co.uk/Find

For me personally, I question whether this works in a world where responsive designs need to scale down to mobile size screens. Surely a single, top navigation that is more consistent across devices is better. What do people think?

Comment: What about your example site makes it have an inverted-L style navigation? I looked at it every which way I can think of and am unable to find any L-shaped structure to it. Normal or inverted? Could you add a mock-up to your question to visualize what your mean? It will also help make this site stand on its own two feet (in case the link rots...) Btw, when editing your question, the icon of the image with a pencil opens up the embedded mock-up editor.

Comment: See related: [What's the best approach for header/footer in responsive web design?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37484/whats-the-best-approach-for-header-footer-in-responsive-web-design/37487#37487)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately responsive design is about presenting the best interface for a number of given screen solutions.  While it may be technically challenging to scale down and transform an inverted-L navigation structure (or scale up in the case of a mobile-first design), this has little bearing on whether or not it is the best interface for the desktop resolution.

Your other question regarding whether or not navigation structure should be consistent across devices is a good one, but I don't necessarily think navigation must be consistent across devices.  If a larger screen real estate gives you the chance to present a more optimal navigation structure, you should take advantage of that - which is what responsive design is all about, right?